# Upside down vs downside up

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, colloquialisms

Typically when something is reversed or inverted we say it is "upside down", could we also say that it is also "downside up"?

For example...

> "The picture is upside down"

could we also say it like this...

> The picture is downside up

Are there any sort of rules for the latter? I know it doesn't get used much (if it all) but is it still valid?

Comment: I wouldn't call the second example incorrect, but it is unidiomatic.  I would only expect to hear it in direct comparison to *upside down*. // *'This picture is upside down!' 'No, I think you mean "downside up"!'* Cue awkward laughter.

Comment: Most native speakers would consider that bass-ackwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a supplement to @Anonym's comment, here's a [Google Ngram comparing the two.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upside+down%2Cdownside+up&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=8&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupside%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownside%20up%3B%2Cc0). To say something is "downside up" is grammatically correct (and thus 'valid' in a narrow sense), but *completely unidiomatic*. I don't think there's any practical usage of the term, outside of discussing the distinction (as we are now):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, "upside down" is a phraseological unit which can be found in a dictionary. If any word or expression is put into a dictionary (I mean, some serious dicitonary, for example, one from Oxford series), it is considered to be correct. The expression "downside up" is not enlisted in any dictionary, instead English speakers use the expression "right side up". In fact, "downside up" is possible, because its structure is based on the analogy with "upside down" (analogy in linguistics is one of the processes which reduces any word forms perceived as incorrect or unusual to the more common forms governed by the language rules; e.g. the verb "to dive" in American English has the past form "dove" which is based on the analogy with the verb "to drive" = "drove"). If this expression is "lucky" enough and gets some popularity due to its usage in mass media or just in everyday life, it can be put into a dictionary and become correct from the point of view of the language system.

Comment: Your observations are correct as far as they go, but as Anonym's comment to the OP suggests, when you use a novel collocation that -- for no obvious reason -- reverses a familiar one, you will most likely encounter puzzlement and/or incomprehension.

Comment: 'Downside up' isn't in common use in the Northern hemisphere. Seriously, ['Siamese twins'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_(linguistics)) and related two-component expressions are usually fixed ordered pairs, like spic and span, come and go, to and fro....

Comment: Agree that "downside up" is not a common expression. "Upside down" and "downside up" are logically the same condition: Normal configuration is reversed. Related: inside-out and outside-in are the same. When my daughter was small, she would ask, "Is this inside-out, or outside-out?"

Answer (score 0):

Well. I think it can be used as a "poetic" expression or used to "play" with the comparison to upside down. In fact, a song by Hilary Duff titled "Jericho" starts like this:

> Hop a fast train out of town
>   Downside up and upside down
>   Going fast is going slow
>   What could've been we'll never know

And "upside down" means that the place or part that should be up is down. So "downside up" should mean that the place or part that should be down is up.